# Create variable sized header

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two different views, one on top of another. Between both of them they must fit the whole screen. The view on the Bottom is a ListView that may contain any number of elements. The header or Top view is an overlayed image of at least minimum size 120dp and max of 300dp, but resized (and cropped) to fit any space the Bottom view is not using.

My current xml is not working.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/drawer_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_image_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="120dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds= "true"
            android:maxHeight="300dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="230dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/header_name" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/header_name_separator"
                    android:layout_width="6dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/header_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_lock_idle_low_battery"
                    android:textOff=""
                    android:textOn="" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/event_image_holder" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There is no logcat. It's a visual artefact not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to manually ask for a measurement of the anchored ListView and screen size, and resize the element dynamically through several points in the app.